# echo >> not working

Tags: shell, io-redirection, echo

This is what I am trying to achieve step by step:

1. ls
2. then reverse it's output
3. then add a new line to the last of this file

Accordingly, I have made the following one line script but it's giving error

```
(ls | tac | echo >>) > ./foobar
```

I can do this by splitting into multiple commands but I am trying to do this in one single command.

I am confused because `echo >> ./foobar` inserts a new line to the end of file.

Then why is my line of code not working? Why `echo >>` is not adding new line at the end of file descriptor but giving error instead? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you do `ls | tac | echo >>`. Do you get a result that you expect?

Comment: AFAIK `echo` doesn't accept standard input; you probably want to simply chain the commands e.g. `( ls | tac; echo ) > foobar` or if your shell supports command grouping `{ ls | tac; echo; } > foobar` avoiding the subshell

Comment: @steeldriver got my answer, yes you're right

Comment: In the spirit of simplification, the same results can be achieved using native `ls` options, eliminating the need for the useless `tac`.  Try `ls -1r` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your command is parsed:

- `(…)` is a compound command. The content of the parentheses is executed in a subshell.

  - `ls | tac | echo >>` is a pipeline consisting of three parts: `ls`, `tac` and `echo >>`. The leftmost part's output is connected to the second part's input, and the second part's output is connected to the rightmost part's input.
  - `ls` is a simple command, executing an executable file.
  - `tac` is a simple command, executing an executable file.
  - `echo >>` is not syntactically correct. The `>>` operator needs to be followed by a file name, and the file name is missing.
- `> ./foobar` redirects the output of the compound command to the file `./foobar`.

Directing input to `echo` doesn't make sense: it doesn't read any input. To use `echo` to append to the output of some other command, run `echo` *after* the other command, not in parallel.

```
ls | tac; echo
```

The output of `echo` is going to the same place as the output of `tac`, so there's no need for any redirection.

```
( ls | tac; echo ) >./foobar
```

You don't need a subshell here. A simple grouping will do. (See [Simple logical operators in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803) for a summary of bash's parenthesis-like operators.)

```
{ ls | tac; echo; } >./foobar
```

Using the `>>` operator to *append* would only be needed if you were appending to an already-existing file. This is not the case here: all the commands go to the same location, the file `foobar` is only opened once, and remains open as long as the whole compound command is executing. The `>>` operator would be needed if you opened the file twice:

```
ls | tac >./foobar; echo >>./foobar
```

Answer (score 3):

The `>>` tells the shell to append the commands output to the filename directly following the symbols (so you would at least have to add a name before the closing bracket).

For what you would like to do, you could either do:

```
ls | tac > ./foobar; echo >>./foobar
```

or:

```
(ls | tac; echo ) >./foobar
```

Both are achieving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the result as specified, it is possible to do:

```
echo -e "`ls | tac`\n" > ./foobar
```

In this way, the output of `ls` is piped through `tac`. The result is contained within the `echo` command, and the escape character interpretation of `echo` will add a new line. The stdout can then be redirected to a file.

I do not believe it is possible to pipe stdout into echo.

Comment: Doesn't work with file names containing backslashes.

Comment: @Gilles, then don't do that :) While I agree there are corner cases, there is also worrying about things that 99% of people don't do, and no where was it enumerated as a requirement. As also noted, there may not be the need for the `tac` command, using instead `ls -1r` for example.